# How to get rid of white space in mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css

The website is getfarmerfit.com

It looks okay on the desktop version unless you zoom out to 50%. It then shows the white space to the right of the [slider that's created by with jQuery](http://www.htmldrive.net/go/to/simple-images-scroller). I've tried overflow-x-hidden and it didn't work. I've tried finding some metas that were claimed to have no scaling/zooming out capability on the mobile version and still that din't work.

Any suggestion would be useful.

```css
.scroller_roll{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*overflow-y: auto;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    align-self: center;
}
.scroller_roll ul{
    align-self: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller_roll ul li{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    align-self: center;
    /*clear: both;*/
    /*text-align: center;*/
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scroller_roll ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.scroller_roll ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.scroller_roll ul li a img{
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Slide Show -->

<!-- <div id=="tech-slideshow">
 <div class="tech-slideshow">
    <div class="mover-1"></div>
    <div class="mover-2"></div>
 </div>
</div> -->
<div id="scroller_roll1" class="scroller_roll">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/elaine_dips.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/fierce_randy.jpg" width="300" height="300"  alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/janette_swings.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/johany_back.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/jose_pushdowns.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/large_group.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/leah_flys.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/randy_sled.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/shoulder_press.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/steven_pullups.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/leah_leg_out.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/renegade_row_girls.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/side_plank.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/leah_guns.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/three_ladies.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
        <li><img src="img/resources/css_slider_images/woman_pushups.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Farmer Fitness"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<!-- Slide Show Ends -->
```

Comment: please provide some code or jsfiddle

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Post effort and code

Comment: See, After linking to the scroller and showing the HTML/Style now the question fits SO.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to show the exact problem you want to see?
Also, 50% zoom is not necessarily a mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to wrap the scroller in another div and apply "overflow-x: hidden" to that and it eliminated the issue.